# Should I use SSD Caching on non bootable HD?

Tags: ssd, cache

I have an asus 9p79x pro which allows me to do SSD Caching. I have a 256 GB SSD drive that I use as my primary boot drive, and I have a 1 TB disk where I put most of my games, music, videos, dowloads, pictures, etc. I also have an extra 64 GB SSD Drive that I'm currently not using. I thought it would be a good idea to use it as my 1 TB disk cache and improve the load time of games and programs that are installed on the 1 TB disk; but will this work correctly? It seems, from all that I have read online about this board, that it is used to cache a boot drive.

Any thoughts?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously since your boot drive is SSD, you will not see any benefits from the caching on the primary boot device.

However, since your other drive is a platter, you definitely would. Although, it may be pointless to do this if you were only loading videos onto your second drive. Since you are putting games, music, pictures, etc. on this drive, you will notice a speed boost. Personally, I have a RAID1 platter used for videos, RAID0 128GB for SSD primary boot, and a secondary platter for music/apps/pictures on a SSD Cached/Platter. Everything seems to work just fine and fast. Since my movies basically stream/load while I watch them, I'm not worried about having that data included in my cache. It would only take up valuable SSD space.

In short, whenever you have a bunch of smaller files on a platter drive, caching the data on a SSD drive will increase the performance noticeably.

Answer (score 1):

> **Should** I use SSD Caching on non bootable HD?

Obviously an answer to this can be quite opinionated, still: If you already have a spare SSD and room in your desktop, then why not use it?

The more interesting question is on how to use it. E.g.

- Can you leverage the chipsets caching method for a non-boot drive?
- Or do you use another method (e.g. [ZFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS)).
- Or just mount the drive as an extra folder in a volume on the HDD to speed up a specific set pf games?

etc etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I guess I was not very clear, but I was referring to the asus "exclusive solution" for ssd caching (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhCGo0LWaTY).